# Error during SqlBulkCopy WriteToServer - Message (Incorrect syntax near 'ALLOW_ENCRYPTED_VALUE_MODIFICATIONS'.))

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sqlbulkcopy, visual-studio-2019

I was trying to upload the data from my datatable using `SqlBulkCopy`. But after the line goes to `WriteToServer(dt)` the system  returns an exception

> Incorrect syntax near 'ALLOW_ENCRYPTED_VALUE_MODIFICATIONS'

I've already tried adding `sqlBulkCopyOptions` but the error is still the same.

```vb
Dim mapSessionNo As New SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping, mapBatchID As New SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping, mapPolicyID As New SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping, mapUpdateDts As New SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping, mapID As New SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping

Dim bulkcopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers & SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints & SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity & SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction)
bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "BatchUpdateLog"

mapSessionNo = New SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("SessionNo", "SessionNo")
mapBatchID = New SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("BatchID", "BatchID")
mapPolicyID = New SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("PolicyID", "PolicyID")
mapUpdateDts = New SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("UpdateDts", "UpdateDts")
mapID = New SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("ID", "ID")
bulkcopy.NotifyAfter = 10000
bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapID)
bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapSessionNo)
bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapBatchID)
bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapPolicyID)
bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapUpdateDts)
bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dt)
bulkcopy.Close()
```

I expect the whole data table will be uploaded to the database. But the system returns an error when it comes to the `WriteToServer` line of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the issue is that here:

```vb
Dim bulkcopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers & SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints & SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity & SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction)
```

you are performing string concatenation on the `SqlBulkCopyOptions` values instead of combination.  You combine `Enum` values with a bitwise `Or`.  I suspect that you were going for a bitwise `And`, which would still be wrong.  In C#, the `&` operator is a bitwise `And` but it's string concatenation in VB.  That should be:

```vb
Dim bulkcopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers Or SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints Or SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity Or SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction)
```

EDIT: It's a bit counter-intuitive that you need to use `Or` when, logically, you want one value AND another value.  It's perfectly logical if you understand bitwise logic though.  Bitwise logic is basically Boolean logic on the individual bits of a numeric value.  Let's say that you have two `Enum` values where one has the numeric value 4 and the other has the value 32.  In binary, those two values would look like this:

```
0000 0100
0010 0000
```

Bitwise operations work on corresponding pairs of bits and treat 1 as TRUE and 0 as FALSE.  In Boolean logic, the result of an OR operation is TRUE if either operand is TRUE, otherwise it is FALSE.  That means that, in bitwise operations, a bit in the result will be 1 if either of the corresponding bits in the operands is 1, otherwise it will be 0.  That means that the result of a bitwise OR on those two values will have a 1 anywhere either operand has a 1 and a 0 everywhere else:

```
0010 0100
```

If you did a bitwise AND then the result would only have a 1 where both operands had a 1 and 0 everywhere else.  Those two operands don't both have a 1 anywhere so the result would be all 0:

```
0000 0000
```

When it comes to `Enums`, you use bitwise OR to combine, bitwise AND to mask, bitwise AND NOT to test and bitwise XOR to toggle.  By "mask" I mean remove all but certain values.  For instance, let's say that you have an unknown combination of the same `Enum` as before and you want to mask out all but the 4 and 32 values.  You would first combine 4 and 32 with a bitwise OR and then AND that with your current value.  The result of a bitwise AND will have a 1 where both operands have a 1, so it can only have a 1 in the 4 or 32 position but it will only have a 1 in those positions if the original value does, e.g. if the original value was:

```
1010 1010
```

and we AND it with:

```
0010 0100
```

then we get:

```
0010 0000
```

Hopefully this helps a bit with bitwise logic.

Comment: Thanks this fixed the issue. But I have a new error "Cannot find the object "BatchUpdateLog" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.". I already checked the server and I'm using the correct table

Comment: I already fixed the issue. I changed the db server role and give it bulkadmin role. thank you. your answer really helped alot

Answer (score 0):

1. have you tried `SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default`?
2. or what about the ALLOW_ENCRYPTED_VALUE_MODIFICATIONS user property? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I've already tried the sqlbulkcopyoptions.default but it still gives the same issue.